# mod_wsgi Causing httpd to Segmentation Fault

Tags: centos, mod-wsgi, segmentation-fault

I have just installed python2.6 and mod_wsgi on my MediaTemple CentOS5.8 server.  I had to install python2.6 along side the default python version of 2.4.  I then compiled mod_wsgi telling it to use python2.6.  Everything compiled and built fine.

I added this line to the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

`"LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"`

When I restart httpd this causes a segmentation fault

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00007fffececf6a5 in PyEval_ReInitThreads () at Python/ceval.c:312
    312     threading = PyMapping_GetItemString(tstate->interp->modules
```

As far as I know I do not have any config files that actually use mod_wsgi yet, I have not gotten that far in the process.

Does anyone know what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mod_python and mod_wsgi don't coexist very happily, at least not in my configuration.  Luckily I did not need mod_python, so I stopped it from being loaded by apache and everything worked.